# Control caracteres espciales .NET

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, vb.net, oracle, .net

Mi aplicación (WCF/WPF) comparte bbdd con otras aplicaciones realizadas en distintas tencnologías. En ocasiones, al devolver un conjunto de resultados encuentro que algún elemento tiene caracteres especiales. Ejemplo:

*TEXTO DE EJEMPLO    PARA PREGUNTA EN STACKOVERFLOW□□□□□□□□       9999999*

Esos cuadraditos hacen que se rompa el soap de respuesta, lo que hace necesario utilizar la función REGEXP_REPLACE de Oracle para eliminar caracteres no imprimibles en la consulta, para formar el conjunto de resultados y evitar problemas (Exactamente utilizo: `REGEXP_REPLACE({0},'[^[:print:]]'`)

Mi pregunta es:
Dado que en mi aplicación WPF se permite copiar y pegar desde otros softwares, inet etc. ¿Qué función puedo utilizar para limpiar los posibles caracteres especiales (que a veces son invisibles al usuario)? No puedo evitar que los demás los graben, pero quiero evitar grabarlos yo desde mi aplicación.
¿Hay alguna función equivalente al REGEXP_REPLACE de Oracle en .NET que pueda utilizar? ¿Qué otro tipo de caracteres pueden darme problemas en el soap?

Un saludo.

Comment: Puedes probar con `var str=Regex.Replace(str, @"\p{C}+", string.Empty);`

Answer (score 0):

si es una constante □□□□□□□□ 9999999 puedes hacer o probar esto

```
string salida = "TEXTO DE EJEMPLO PARA PREGUNTA EN STACKOVERFLOW□□□□□□□□ 9999999";
string resultado = "";

resultado = salida.Substring(0, salida.Length - (salida.Length - salida.IndexOf("□□□□□□□□ 9999999")));
```

Comment: otra solucion seria: resultado = Regex.Replace(salida, "□□□□□□□□ 9999999", string.Empty);